# ZoomControlStyle - Large 'small' buttons

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am making a custom Google Map and trying to get the `ZoomControl` to look like the one [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-options), but if I use `ZoomControlStyle.SMALL` I get very small zoom controls (see first screenshot) and if I use `ZoomControlStyle.LARGE` I also get small zoom buttons but also the 'bar' (second screenshot).

I was wondering if there was a way to get the [larger zoom control without the bar](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-options), I can't seem to find the option in the documentation and if you directly copy the code they supply, it shows up different than they display, oddly enough.

[image: small zoom control]
`ZoomControlStyle.SMALL`

[image: large zoom control]
`ZoomControlStyle.LARGE`

[image: desired zoom control]
???

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: The only relevant piece of code is the `ZoomControlStyle.X`. I am using their example code from the pages I linked, and getting the small icons like in the images. Are you getting the larger icons?

Comment: On the page you link to in the documentation I am.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set "signed_in=true" in the API include.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry&signed_in=true"></script>
```

[fiddle demonstating that UI](http://jsfiddle.net/cw34pkvy/3/embedded/result/)

See [the documentation on signed in maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/signedin) for more details.