# Styling of the controls using Google Maps API V3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have had a look around but couldn't find anything on this. When looking at the Google samples for their API integration, the controls are more modern than when I implement the same code. So on Google's website the map selection is a image symbolising a map/satellite in the bottom left corner. No matter what I do, I can only get that selection to appear as a horizontal bar or dropdown.

Also their zoom controls look a little more modern than what actually implements when you use the code.

Has anyone else had this issue? Could it be that they are half way through updating their systems?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You can style your custom controls the way you like. Zoom and other controls can be at different positions and/or simplified but can't be much styled using the API. See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeControlOptions).

Comment: Well I just had a look at the samples and you are right, they look a bit different. I have tried setting the version to 3.exp but it doesn't seem to change anything. That is a bit strange.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ZoomControlStyle - Large 'small' buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335912/zoomcontrolstyle-large-small-buttons)

Answer (score 1):

Looking closer at [their code](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/control-options) it looks like the *modern* style is applied when you add the `signed_in=true` to the API call:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
```

The zoom controls and the pegman are automatically moved to the bottom right corner too.

> When sign-in is enabled, the default position and appearance of several controls will change.

And that only happens with the `3.18` version and above (incl. `3.exp`).

> To enable sign-in on a map created with the Google Maps JavaScript API, load v3.18 or later of the API with the additional signed_in=true parameter.

Documentation is here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/signedin